# How do you optimize navigation bar for resizing?

Tags: css, html, resize, navbar, nav

I just started learning html and css about 6 days ago. I do it for a hour a day and I'm having a lot of fun with it. I try to figure most of the issue I have on my own, but I've been having troubles finding resources to fix this problem.

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather);

*
{
    text-decoration: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body
{
    background-color: #ff9900;
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
}

#page
{
    margin: -8px;
}

#wrapper
{
    /*margin: 1px;*/
}

h2>a 
{
    margin: -25px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffde00;
    color: #097054;
    padding: 20px;
}

h2>a:hover 
{
    color: #ffde00;
    transition: .5s ease;
    background-color: #6599ff;
}

.container
{
    padding: 6px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #097054;
}

ul li
{
    background-color: #ffde00;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #097054;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 14pt;
}


ul li:hover
{
    transition: .5s ease;
    background-color: #097054;
    border-color: #25C1BC;
    color: #ffde00;

}

#p1
{
    color: #097054;
    height: 25em;
    width: 25em;
    background-color: #097054;
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
}

p
{
    background-color: #ffde00;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
}

#p1:hover;
{
    /*background-color: #000000;*/
}

p:hover
{
    height: -75%;
    width: -75%;
    padding-bottom: 3.8em;
    box-shadow: -5px -5px 0px 0px #097054;
    margin-top: 3em;
    color: #ffde00;
    background-color: #6599ff;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Essentially what happens is that my navbar will become extremely disorganized after resizing. This causes links to overlap and look really awful.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

http://jsfiddle.net/JZ9LZ/

Answer (score 0):

Add this `.container{white-space: nowrap;}`
This question has been asked before [Disable line breaks using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383483/disable-line-breaks-using-css)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to solve your problem with only html/css as your li elements's width is minimum.

You should decrease the text font-size calculating it on the windows width, but this can be made only with javascript

My advice is to leave this page as before (as I imagine that is only for fun) and when you have good html/css skills you can start studying jQuery <- Very important for the UI