# Rails prevent column from breaking

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, I have a table with four columns.  I want two of the columns to essentially never break if at all possible.  I want the other columns to shrink and continue breaking while these two remain the same.  Currently, shrinking my window simply causes all of the columns to break at the same time and shrink the table to half its size, and it ends up much smaller than the screen.
I've tried using col-sm-2, col-md-2, etc. but these aren't changing the breakpoint for me at all.
Essentially my issue is that all of my columns break at the same point, which is behavior I do not want

Comment: Share you code please. Otherwise, it is not clear what table are you talking about. Especially mixing Rails, bootstrap CSS grid classes and HTML table.

Comment: that's not rails question, it's bootstrap/css question

Answer (score 0):

I think, that's css related, not rails. Anyway, Try with `white-space: nowrap;`

similar SO questions:

[How to prevent line breaks in list items using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383143/how-to-prevent-line-breaks-in-list-items-using-css)

[Disable line breaks using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383483/disable-line-breaks-using-css)